# componentDidMount screen change

Tags: react-native

do I enable data recall when switching between screens.

I can call once with this code

```
async componentDidMount() {
 return fetch("https://www.xxxx.com/app/messages", options)
}
```

Comment: Please add more information about the navigation library you are using. For example if you are using react-navigation you could hook into a navigation event - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html

Answer (score 1):

I solved

```
async componentDidMount() {
    this.load()
    this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.load)
}
load = async () => { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Starts when rendering on a screen that has moved `componentDidMount` as the code in the question. You can use `fetch` as a question to import data.

**LifeCycle**
[image: life cycle]

**Example**

```js
 componentDidMount() {
  return fetch("https://www.xxxx.com/app/messages", options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      this.setState({
         resdata: responseJson.data
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the navigation library you're using. As stated by @Brien Crean, if your routing lib is [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/), then you can check [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html).

If you're on [React Native Navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/), you'd check [here](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/events?id=componentdidappear).

I strongly recommend to use some routing library to handle navigation inside your application, otherwise intercepting events (like components show/hide) would be really hard.

Comment: doesn't work when I put the following code in componentDidMount
this.navigationEventListener = Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);